# Using a Variable in a Table Creation Script

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I'm having some difficulty in creating a PL/SQL block.  The purpose of my script is to pull a report based on the last month's totals in a table (which has already been created as table name "countpull").  I want to use the name of the month in my script to create the table, but Oracle is returning an error "ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement", pointing at the CREATE TABLE command below.

```
DECLARE
  curMonthChar NVARCHAR2(25);
  curTableName NVARCHAR2(50);
  tableexists NUMBER := 0;

BEGIN
  SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate,-1),'fmMONTH') INTO curMonthChar FROM DUAL;
  SELECT ('QP17414_'||curMonthChar) INTO curTableName FROM DUAL;

  --Check to see if current month's count table exists
  SELECT COUNT(1) INTO tableexists FROM all_tab_columns WHERE OWNER = (SELECT USER FROM DUAL) AND table_name = curTableName;

  --If current month's count table exists, drop it
  IF tableexists > 0 THEN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE '||curTableName;
  END IF;

  --Create current month's count table
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '
  CREATE TABLE '||curTableName||' AS (
    SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT movetype, phone_flag, state FROM countpull
      )
    PIVOT (
      COUNT(state)
      FOR state IN ('''||'AA'||''','''||'AE'||''','''||'AK'||''','''||'AL'||'''
        ,'''||'AP'||''','''||'AR'||''','''||'AS'||''','''||'AZ'||''','''||'CA'||'''
        ,'''||'CO'||''','''||'CT'||''','''||'DC'||''','''||'DE'||''','''||'FL'||'''
        ,'''||'FM'||''','''||'GA'||''','''||'GU'||''','''||'HI'||''','''||'IA'||'''
        ,'''||'ID'||''','''||'IL'||''','''||'IN'||''','''||'KS'||''','''||'KY'||'''
        ,'''||'LA'||''','''||'MA'||''','''||'MD'||''','''||'ME'||''','''||'MH'||'''
        ,'''||'MI'||''','''||'MN'||''','''||'MO'||''','''||'MP'||''','''||'MS'||'''
        ,'''||'MT'||''','''||'NC'||''','''||'ND'||''','''||'NE'||''','''||'NH'||'''
        ,'''||'NJ'||''','''||'NM'||''','''||'NV'||''','''||'NY'||''','''||'OH'||'''
        ,'''||'OK'||''','''||'OR'||''','''||'PA'||''','''||'PR'||''','''||'PW'||'''
        ,'''||'RI'||''','''||'SC'||''','''||'SD'||''','''||'TN'||''','''||'TX'||'''
        ,'''||'UT'||''','''||'VA'||''','''||'VI'||''','''||'VT'||''','''||'WA'||'''
        ,'''||'WI'||''','''||'WV'||''','''||'WY'||''')
    ))';

END;
```

The script above works just fine when I don't try to use a variable for the table name.  But since I want the table name to dynamically change every time the script is run, I want to avoid using a static name.

Why is it invalid to create a table with a dynamic table name in a PL/SQL block?

Additional info:

The table schema for countpull is

```
state NVARCHAR2(2),
movetype NVARCHAR2(1),
phone_flag NVARCHAR2(1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reasons that aren't immediately clear to me, the problem is that the variable you're using is `nvarchar2`. It works if you declare it as `varchar2`:

```
  curTableName VARCHAR2(50);
```

Validated via [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7e8d7); that fiddle fails if you just change the declaration of the table name variable to `nvarchar2`.

As @jonearles points out, the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e17126/executeimmediate_statement.htm#sthref1287) does state that the command string's 'type must be either `CHAR`, `VARCHAR2`, or `CLOB`'. And although the documentation for [the concatenation operator](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/operators003.htm) doesn't refer to it, the related [`concat` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/functions033.htm) does state that 'if one of the arguments is a national data type, then the returned value is a national data type' - so your command string is `nvarchar2` because the variable you're using in the concatenation is `nvarchar2`, making the argument to the `execute immediate` statement illegal.

It's not a great idea to create tables on the fly though. Schema objects should normally be created once. You could have a table - possibly a global temporay table - with a month column, or at a push twelve tables that you empty and populate as needed.

Also, all your `select from dual` statements could be simplified:

```
  curMonthChar := TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate,-1),'fmMONTH');
  curTableName := 'QP17414_'||curMonthChar);
```

etc., even in your subquery:

```
... WHERE OWNER = user AND ...
```

... and I have no idea why you're using so much concatenation in your pivot clause.

Comment: The [manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/executeimmediate_statement.htm#LNPLS1201) does not explain why, it only says the dynamic SQL string "...must be either CHAR, VARCHAR2, or CLOB."

Comment: @jonearles - thanks - I had that section open in another tab and still couldn't see it. I've added doc links for the concatenation making the overall dynamic string `nvarchar2` as well, which also wasn't immediately obvious.

Comment: Thank you Alex, that seems to have been the problem.  This is my first real foray into PL/SQL after switching over from SQL Server so I've got quite a bit to learn.  The concatenation in my pivot is a result of the many steps I had taken to try to figure out what was "invalid" about my SQL.  I thought that I must be setting up the pivot up incorrectly.  Thank you also for the suggestions simplification. As far as using, nvarchar2, I have to chalk that up to developing a learned bad habit of not paying close enough attention to using the correct data types for the need.